# Show Progressdialog on AlertDialog button click

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I want to show a ProgressDialog when the User clicks a "Ok" button on the AlertDialog. But with my current code the ProgressDialog doesnt show at all. Also the AlertDialog should dismiss after button click and the ProgressDialog should be shown. Right now the AlertDialog dismisses after button click but does not show the ProgressDialog

Here is my code:-

```
 case R.id.btnAddComms:
            scrollNews.fullScroll(v.FOCUS_DOWN);
            btnAddComms.setPressed(true);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewsDetails.this);
            builder.setTitle("Post");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.post);


            final EditText input1 = new EditText(NewsDetails.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            input1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            builder.setView(input1);


            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {


                     postedComment = input1.getText().toString();

                     if(postedComment.length()>0)
                     {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                         ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(NewsDetails.this);
                         pd.setMessage("test");
                         pd.show();
                         pd.setCancelable(true);
                         PostComments(postedComment);
                         pd.dismiss();

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(NewsDetails.this, "Please enter a comment.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         input1.findFocus();
                     }






                }
.setCancelable(false);



            alert = builder.create();
            alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            alert.show();
            break;
```

Any idea on how I can do it.

Comment: You are closing Your progressdialog immediately after showing it on button click. I don´t know what PostComments is doing, but You should do some workaround. I think the Dialog should close after PostComment has been executed, right? Like You have done it, pd.close() will not wait until PostComments is executed

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Iam dismissing the `dialog` which is the ALertDialog. PostComments is making a API call

Comment: Try removing `pd.dismiss();`

Comment: no You don´t. first You are dismiss the alertDialog with dialog.dismiss(). this is correct, but at last, You write pd.dismiss(). pd is Your ProgressDialog

Comment: dialog.dismiss(); is given after the pd.dismiss(); so your code is  ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(NewsDetails.this);
                         pd.setMessage("test");
                         pd.show();
                         pd.setCancelable(true);
                         PostComments(postedComment);
 pd.dismiss();
dialog.dismiss();

Comment: @Aniruddha I tried it. The ProgressDialog now shows after the AlertDialog is dismissed and PostComments is executed. Also, It does not go away

Comment: put the dialog.dismiss() after pd.dismiss();

Answer (score 1):

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            PostComments(postedComment);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: what is the use of this in this above code?can u explain ?

Comment: @Digvesh this is not what I was asking

Comment: Not only will this "freeze" the UI (including the progress dialog) while the method is running, which is bad practice in general, this will also make the app crash because the method preforms network operations, which you can't do on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move `dialog.dismiss();` to the end of the code being called when the button is clicked... you don't want the dialog to remove itself before it's done executing relevant code...
Next, you're dismissing your progress dialog right after showing it. I would suggest you declare the progress dialog global by placing the line: `ProgressDialog pd;` at the top of the class and changing the line:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(NewsDetails.this);
```

to:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(NewsDetails.this);
```

And lastly, remove the `pd.dismiss();` line from the code being called when the button is being clicked, and place it at the end of the `PostComments(postedComment);` method, so the method removes the progress dialog when it finishes.
You mentioned the method executes an API call. if it's in an ASyncTask, place the `pd.dismiss();` line in the `onPostExecute` part.
Good luck! :)

--- EDIT ---

Ok, after better understanding the issue at hand, you can also try declaring your alert box builder global as well, defining and showing it in the "ok" button's onClickListener, and dismissing it at the end of the `PostComments(postedComment);` method (exactly like you did with the progress dialog). This should work.

Btw, I would personally prefer, instead of having 2 dialogs on the screen at once, to design my own custom dialog that has the progress bar already inside it. Then, use the `View.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE / View.INVISIBLE)` methods to make the progress bar appear and disappear as I please. Of course, you will still have to declare it globally and dismiss it at the end of the `PostComments(postedComment);` method, but it'll look a bit cleaner (in my opinion), both in the code, and to the user.
The [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) has a pretty good explanation about creating custom dialogs. If it's not enough, tell me and I'll provide an example.

Comment: I tried what you said. But still the progressdialog shows after the alert box is dismissed and not on button click

Comment: I must have misunderstood what you are trying to do. Do you want the alert box to stay there while the progress dialog is shown, and have them both dismiss when the "post comments" method finishes?

Comment: any solution for my problem

Comment: Did you try my updated answer? Please accept my answer if it worked. Thanks